# How to change the default button caption on VerticalStepperForm?

Tags: android, stepper

I'm using [VerticalStepperForm](https://github.com/ernestoyaquello/VerticalStepperForm) to implement a survey form like this:
[image]

**DiagnosaActivity.java**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.diasni.app.diagnosa.steps.StepPertanyaan;

import ernestoyaquello.com.verticalstepperform.VerticalStepperFormView;
import ernestoyaquello.com.verticalstepperform.listener.StepperFormListener;

public class DiagnosaActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements StepperFormListener {

    VerticalStepperFormView verticalStepperForm;
    StepPertanyaan pertanyaan01, pertanyaan02, pertanyaan03, pertanyaan04, pertanyaan05, pertanyaan06, pertanyaan07,
            pertanyaan08, pertanyaan09, pertanyaan10;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_diagnosa);

        pertanyaan01 = new StepPertanyaan("Apakah perut kanan bawah anda sakit?");
        pertanyaan02 = new StepPertanyaan("Apakah anda demam?");
        pertanyaan03 = new StepPertanyaan("Apakah anda mual?");
        pertanyaan04 = new StepPertanyaan("Apakah anda muntah?");
        pertanyaan05 = new StepPertanyaan("Apakah anda tidak nafsu makan?");
        pertanyaan06 = new StepPertanyaan("Apakah anda merasa lelah?");
        pertanyaan07 = new StepPertanyaan("Apakah anda sering buang air kecil?");
        pertanyaan08 = new StepPertanyaan("Apakah anda diare?");
        pertanyaan09 = new StepPertanyaan("Apakah nyeri pinggang belakang anda?");
        pertanyaan10 = new StepPertanyaan("Apakah anda pusing?");

        verticalStepperForm = findViewById(R.id.stepper_form);
        verticalStepperForm.setup(this, pertanyaan01, pertanyaan02, pertanyaan03, pertanyaan04, pertanyaan05
        , pertanyaan06, pertanyaan07, pertanyaan08, pertanyaan09, pertanyaan10).init();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletedForm() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelledForm() {

    }
}
```

**StepPertanyaan.java**

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.diasni.app.diagnosa.R;

import ernestoyaquello.com.verticalstepperform.Step;

public class StepPertanyaan extends Step<String> {

    RadioGroup rgJawaban;
    RadioButton rbSelected;
    View content;

    public StepPertanyaan(String title){
        this(title, "");
    }

    public StepPertanyaan(String title, String subtitle){
        super(title, subtitle);
    }

    @Override
    public String getStepData() {
        int selectedRadioId = rgJawaban.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        if (selectedRadioId > -1) {
            rbSelected = (RadioButton) content.findViewById(selectedRadioId);
            return rbSelected.getText().toString();
        }
        else return "";
    }

    @Override
    public String getStepDataAsHumanReadableString() {
        int selectedRadioId = rgJawaban.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        if (selectedRadioId > -1) {
            rbSelected = (RadioButton) content.findViewById(selectedRadioId);
            return rbSelected.getText().toString();
        }
        else return "";
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreStepData(String data) {

    }

    @Override
    protected IsDataValid isStepDataValid(String stepData) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected View createStepContentLayout() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_pertanyaan, null, false);
        rgJawaban = (RadioGroup) content.findViewById(R.id.rgJawaban);
        return content;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStepOpened(boolean animated) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStepClosed(boolean animated) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStepMarkedAsCompleted(boolean animated) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStepMarkedAsUncompleted(boolean animated) {

    }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.ernestoyaquello.stepperform:vertical-stepper-form:2.2.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

The questions are already in Indonesian. The Continue button, is of course not. How to change it's caption, then? I already take a look at the Github repo, so far it seems that you have to modify and rebuild the VerticalStepperForm lib. Maybe I'm missing something, though.

Comment: download the library and import the module dependency instead of  library dependency and make the changes directly in the library

Comment: Where is the `Step` class? I can't seem to resolve it :/